# How to remove duplicate li items only for each ul item using javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a dynamically generated navigation structure shown. Each location has storetypes generated from the stores at the location.

I need to remove duplicates per location so that groceries can appear in both locations. I tried the common jquery solution below which removes duplicates  but it results in each storetype appearing only in one location.

```js
var seen = {};
$("ul#storetypes").find("li").each(function(index, html_obj) {
  txt = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

  if (seen[txt]) {
    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    seen[txt] = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Location 1
    <ul id="storetypes" class="sub-menu">
      <li>groceries</li>
      <li>cakes</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>groceries</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Location 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>groceries</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>groceries</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

what you did is correct, but just do it for every `<ul>`.

```js
$("ul.storetypes").each(function() {
  var seen = {};
  $(this).find("li").each(function(index, html_obj) {
    txt = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if (seen[txt]) {
      $(this).remove();
    } else {
      seen[txt] = true;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Location 1
    <ul class="sub-menu storetypes">
      <li>groceries</li>
      <li>cakes</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>groceries</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Location 2
    <ul class="sub-menu storetypes">
      <li>groceries</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>groceries</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works when snipet is run but produces same result in my code. Found solution by @Ying-Shan Lin. Thanks for the effort

Comment: the `<ul>` in location 2 `<li>`, i added class `storetypes`.

Comment: yours should work as well if you have class `storetypes` in all the `<ul>` that you want to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$("ul.sub-menu li").each(function(index, html_obj) {
  if ($(this).prevAll(":contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").length > 0) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

This will look into each `.sub-menu` and see if any 'li' exist already with the same text, and remove the duplicated.

**Demo**

```js
$("ul.sub-menu li").each(function(index, html_obj) {
  if ($(this).prevAll(":contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").length > 0) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Location 1
    <ul id="storetypes" class="sub-menu">
      <li>groceries</li>
      <li>cakes</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>groceries</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Location 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>groceries</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>groceries</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to target your top-level iteration at each sub-list.

Then iterate its children and remove duplicates.

Also, you don't need jQuery.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu").forEach((list) => {
  const seen = new Set();
  list.querySelectorAll(":scope > li").forEach((item) => {
    const text = item.textContent.trim();
    if (seen.has(text)) {
      item.remove();
    } else {
      seen.add(text);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Location 1
    <ul id="storetypes" class="sub-menu">
      <li>groceries</li>
      <li>cakes</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>groceries</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Location 2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>groceries</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>motor spares</li>
      <li>groceries</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Didnt get to try this because another solution worked. Thanks for the effort.